# Phonegap's exitApp() not killing the app?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working on an android app with phonegap (cordova 2.1) and I want the user to be able to fully close the app by clicking a menu button. I have the event set to use  navigator.app.exitApp() but this only seems to close the window and the app continues to run in the background and the music still plays, needing to be force closed. I also set the boolean "keepRunning" to false in my mainAcitvity file.

Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

pls call this methode onclick button

function exitFromApp()
             {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
             }